# Doctrine query builder IN is not working

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called `Continent`. A continent has countries:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Country")
 * @JoinTable(name="cont_countries",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="cont_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 * @var Country[]
 **/
private $countries;
```

I would like to find, which continents belong to a country. (For example Russia belongs to Europe, and Asia too)

I've tried this:

```
$qb->andWhere(':country IN (t.countries)')
->setParameter('country', $country)
// possibly more conditions after that
```

But for some reason, I get `Uncaught exception` because of the `IN` statement

Comment: its `field` IN `values` not values in field :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of country id to the in function.

Try this:

```
$qb->andWhere('t.countries IN (:country)')
->setParameter('country', $country)
```

instead of:

```
$qb->andWhere(':country IN (t.countries)')
   ->setParameter('country', 
                          // Extract id from a collections
                          array_map('current', $country) 
                         );
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @IterAtor What contain `$country`? `$country` should be an array of ids.

Comment: It is an array of country instances

Comment: Hi @IterAtor i update  my answer with a method for extract ids from a collection. Hope this help